# await with pg throws an error

Tags: node.js, pg

I am following the example at [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/) and trying to create a synchronous connection to postgres from nodejs

```
var http = require("http");

const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')
const connectionString = 'postgresql://x:x@localhost:5432/x'

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

   const pool = new Pool({ connectionString: connectionString, })
   await pool.connect()

   const res = await pool.query('SELECT NOW()')
}).listen(3000);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
```

The node.js complains with the error:

```
   await pool.connect()
         ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

what do I do wrong (connecting through event handling works just fine)?

Comment: Assuming you are using node version that supports `async/await` you still need to mark function as async `async function (req, res) {`

Comment: I suppose i used the await version, since i got the most recent version of the module. How can i be sure? How do i mark the function as async?

Comment: Using `async` keyword as I have posted.

Comment: Also you are "shadowing" function argument `const res = ...` Use different name say `const now = ...` or whatever.

Comment: good point. Looks like this solves the problem :-)

Comment: will you do the honors to post it as an answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164052/discussion-between-arthur-and-yury-tarabanko).

Comment: I was quite sure there should already be question like that. Though I couldn't find any good candidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark function as `async` if you want to use `await` keyword inside. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

> The `await` operator is used to wait for a `Promise`. It can only be used
>   inside an **async function**.

```
http.createServer(async function (req, res) { // NB!
   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

   const pool = new Pool({ connectionString: connectionString, })
   await pool.connect()

   // also you were shadowing res argument
   // const res = await pool.query('SELECT NOW()')
   const now = await pool.query('SELECT NOW()')
   res.send(now); 
}).listen(3000);
```